# How to add multiple namespace in XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I am quite new to XSLT. I have the following XML structure. How can I form an XSLT in the similar structure where I can include all the above namespace in the similar way?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<NS1:Envelope xmlns:NS1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <NS1:Body>
    <NS2:Data xmlns:NS2="myurl1.....">
      <NS3:Created xmlns:NS3="myurl2....."></NS3:Created>
      <NS5:Success xmlns:NS5="myurl3....."></NS5:Success>
    </NS2:Data>
  </NS1:Body>
</NS1:Envelope>
```

Comment: It depends on what your stylesheet is doing. In general, if you **copy** elements, their namespaces will be copied too.

Comment: It's not clear if what you show is the input or only the output. If it's the output, please show what your input looks like and what your transformation does.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible in standard XSLT. However, with System.Xml, you can insert namespace nodes in the following way.  I suspect the same works with unmanaged MSXML too, but haven't tried

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
            exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:variable name="fragment">
        <dummy xmlns:foo="bar" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="msxsl:node-set($fragment)/dummy/namespace::foo" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is unnecessary, since all the namespace declarations are being actually used in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You define the namespace with the `xmlns` attribute in the start tag of an element. 
Used alone, it defines the default namespace, associated with a prefix, it defines other namespace (for example xmlns:toto="namespaceURI" )

See [xml namespace](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)
In the example, they define:

```
<root xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/" xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
```

And you can prefix your elements with `h`or `f` in this example

```
<h:table>
<f:table>
```

For your example, use to define NS2:

```
<NS1:Envelope xmlns:NS1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:NS2="YOUR_NAMESPACE_URI_FOR_NS2">
  <NS1:Body>
    <NS2:Data>
      <NS3:Created></NS3:Created>
      <NS5:Success></NS5:Success>
    </NS2:Data>
  </NS1:Body>
</NS1:Envelope>
```

Do the same for NS3, NS5, etc.